# Cannot unlock My Book 3Tb

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I entered the wrong password 5 times. Then I tried erase [My Book](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=870).
The process I started with Disk Security ended with error message.
I tried a few more times with the same result.
Windows Explorer doesn't see it.
Windows Disk Manager says "the disk is locked". I can do nothing with it.

Comment: What was the exact error message?

Comment: Delete and re-add your partitions on that drive.  Disk Management built into windows should do it.  diskpart for sure will do it.  You don't have to boot into linux to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Reformat the external hard drive by booting the [GParted live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). GParted Live is a small bootable GNU/Linux distribution for x86 based computers that enables you to use all the features of the latest versions of the GParted partition editor application. Reformatting the external hard  drive will erase all of the data that is currently stored on it.

If reformatting the external hard drive with GParted isn't possible because the drive is encrypted, try to do a lower level reformatting from a Linux live DVD/USB by following the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496309/how-to-unboot-my-bootable-usb/496328#496328).